# How to Implement Hyperlink Control in windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 microSoft has a new control In metro:Hyperlink,which is to Instead of HyperlinkButton, it is a inline control。 but it did not Compatible with windows 8.

so, I want to Implement Hyperlink in windows 8.

but Inline type didn't have Tapped Event.

I want to ask: "how to add Tapped event into a Inlin type control;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `HyperlinkButton` inside of a `TextBlock's` `Inlines` through a `InlineUIContainer` as in [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/RichTextBlockExtensions.cs).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Appends a HyperlinkButton with
    /// the given text and navigate uri to the given RichTextBlock.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="richTextBlock">The rich text block.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
    public static void AppendLink(this RichTextBlock richTextBlock, string text, Uri uri)
    {
        Paragraph paragraph;

        if (richTextBlock.Blocks.Count == 0 ||
            (paragraph = richTextBlock.Blocks[richTextBlock.Blocks.Count - 1] as Paragraph) == null)
        {
            paragraph = new Paragraph();
            richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }

        var link =
            new HyperlinkButton
            {
                Content = text,
                NavigateUri = uri
            };

        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer { Child = link });
    }
```